# Is there any way to register new client from API endpoint in new Spring Authorization Server 0.3.0?

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

We have implemented new spring authorization server from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server

We have registered few default clients in configuration file.
But now we want to add new clients while this application running on.
Is there any open API endpoint specified for this ?
( There is client registration endpoint for oidc client, but we are not using oidc and anyways it generates client id by itself which we don't want)

Any hint is appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only endpoint provided for registering new clients is the [OpenID Connect 1.0 Client Registration Endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/protocol-endpoints.html#oidc-client-registration-endpoint).

Comment: Thank you for reply. Looks like that is one and only endpoint